# React dynamics image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, reactjs.net

i'm learning the react techologie, i'm the first exercice i must put the images like this, but when i use the map function to put the images i don't saw the images :/

[image dynamics example](https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-React/blob/master/images/frontend_technologies.png)

```
import React from 'react'<br>
import './Style/App.css'


const tabImg = ['./img/html.png', './img/css.png', './img/javascript.png', './img/logo192.png']<br>
const displayImgTech = tabImg.map((tech) => <img key={tech} src={tech}  alt="techno"/>)<br>

export const Header = () => {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <img src={displayImgTech}  alt='technoFE'/>
            </div>
        )
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing `displayImgTech`in the src img props your are not adding an url but an "array" of img tags. so you just need to call {display take in your div like this:

```
const displayImgTech = tabImg.map((tech) => <img key={tech} src={tech}  alt="techno"/>)<br>

export const Header = () => {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
               {displayImgTech} 
            </div>
        )
}
```

[image: Edit modest-williamson-ibycr]

Comment: Thank you very much :)